# Eigenvector help 2x2 matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have $ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\frac{a_{12}}{a_{21}} \\ -\rho \frac{a_{21}}{a_{12}}   & 0 \end{pmatrix} $

For which I get $ \lambda = + \sqrt{\rho}  $

and

$ \lambda = - \sqrt{\rho}  $

However I am not sure how to find the eigenvectors?

\begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{\rho} & -\frac{a_{12}}{a_{21}} \\ -\rho \frac{a_{21}}{a_{12}}   & -\sqrt{\rho} \end{pmatrix} $

\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$

I get two equations

$ \sqrt{\rho} x + \frac{a_{12}}{a_{21}} y = 0 $

$ \rho \frac{a_{21}}{a_{12}}  + \sqrt{\rho} y = 0$

From here i am not sure how to solve for the eigenvectors, The correct answer is
 $ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{a_{12}}{a_{21}}  \\ -\sqrt{\rho} \end{pmatrix}$ which i cannot seem to get. any help appreciated. thank you.

Comment: You system of equation does not have a unique solution.  You get to choose an arbitrary value for $x$(or $y$) and then find the $y$ associated with that $x$.  Might as well choose an $x$ that is easy to work with.  Also keep in mind, that as there is not a unique solution there is not a single "right answer."  Your answer could be a scalar multiple of the book answer.

Comment: I am trying to get that above answer, how?

Comment: With $2\times 2$ matrices, this never fails.  Look at the first equation.  Choose $x = $ coefficient of $y$ and $y =$ negative of the coefficient of $x.$ It never fails.

Comment: by the way, you dropped the $x$ in your representation of the second equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your second equation is wrong (maybe a typo?). The correct equation is
$$
\rho \frac{a_{21}}{a_{12}}x  + \sqrt{\rho} y = 0
$$

Now solving the first equation for $y$ we find
$$
y=-\sqrt{\rho}\frac{a_{21}}{a_{12}}x
$$

annd substituting this in the second equation we have an identity, so the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $\lambda=-\sqrt{\rho}$ is the space of vectors of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
-\sqrt{\rho}\frac{a_{21}}{a_{12}}x
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and, for $x=\frac{a_{12}}{a_{21}}$ we have the eigenvector:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{a_{12}}{a_{21}}\\
-\sqrt{\rho}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

You can do the same for the other eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

By solving the system of linear equations, you will find out they are dependent. That means $ x = -\frac{a_{12}}{(a_{21} * \sqrt(\rho))}  y$. (just pick one of these equations and play with it).
Then you just insert this x to the vector \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}
so you get

\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{a_{12}}{(a_{21} * \sqrt(\rho))}  y \\ y \end{pmatrix}
.
So for y can be any real number (scalar multiple of these constants). In the book, they chose y=1 and performed an algebraic operation on this vector. They multiplied it by $-\sqrt(\rho)$ and that's their answer.